# toLocaleString() doesn't work in Safari browser

Tags: javascript, safari, currency, number-formatting

I used `toLocaleString()` method to input money comma in `javascript. But the problem is, IE and chrome browser result correctly except Safari browser. I delete cache several times but still doesn't work.

```
var test = 12300; 
console.log('test:'+test.toLocaleString());
 // 12,300 in IE,Chrome 
 // 12300 in Safari
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The issue here is that number.toLocaleString is implemented differently on different browsers. On Safari, it chooses not to display with the person-friendly formatting we're used to. It is supported on safari, but its implementation isn't the same as IE, Chrome, or Firefox. See this link: http://forums.asp.net/t/2031925.aspx?toLocaleString+function+is+inconsistent+with+browser+

Also, Safari doesn't support using the locale parameter with toLocaleString, in case you tried setting that:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Comment: oh... very specific and kind answer. Thank you :)

Comment: What was your approach to this problem @naanace?

Comment: I don't know when exactly it changed, but in Safari 10.0.2 I just tried `var num = 123456789; num.toLocaleString()` and it gave me `"123,456,789"`, so it seems to be fixed now? (tested with system default `en-gb` and manually passing `en-us`)

Comment: @Skitterm I just validated this in a javascript console on the latest safari (what @user568458 said). `number.toLocaleString()` works in the latest safari as of the time of this posting.